# How to dropna based on multiple dataframes?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, na

I have 4 dataframes, df1, df2, df3, df4 such that row x in a df corresponds with row x in other dataframes.

I want to drop rows based on if a particular column has NA values.

However, due to the constraint, if I drop row x in one of the dfs, I must also drop it in other dfs, to keep the correspondence.

I could do it generally, by identifying rows in each df, taking the union and then dropping those.

But is there a "pythonic" way of doing this? Are there optimized functions for this kind of task?

Comment: First `merge` or `concat` then `dropna`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#create list of DataFrames
dfs = [df1,df2,df3,df4]

#for each column test non missing values and create union of masks
m = np.logical_and.reduce([x['col'].notna() for x in dfs])

#for each e.g. second column test missing values and create union of masks
#m = np.logical_and.reduce([x.iloc[:, 1].notna() for x in dfs])

#filter list of Dataframes by union of masks
dfs = [x[m] for x in dfs]

#if need separately all DataFrames
df1,df2,df3,df4 = dfs
```

Another idea is create MutiIndex DataFrame, working best if not big DataFrames:

```
#create list of DataFrames
dfs = [df1,df2,df3,df4]

#join DataFrames together
df_big = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=('df1','df2','df3','df4'))

#remove all rows with missing values by col by keeping non NaNs rows
df_big = df_big[df_big.xs('col', axis=1, level=1).notna().all(axis=1)]

#solution with dropna
#df_big = df_big.dropna(subset=df_big.loc[:, (slice(None), 'col')].columns)

#if need separately all DataFrames
df1, df2, df3, df4 = df_big['df1'],df_big['df2'],df_big['df3'],df_big['df4']
```

**Sample**:

```
np.random.seed(2123)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(8, size=(4,3))).mask(lambda x: x.gt(5))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(8, size=(4,3))).mask(lambda x: x.gt(5))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(8, size=(4,3))).mask(lambda x: x.gt(5))
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(8, size=(4,3))).mask(lambda x: x.gt(5))

#create list of DataFrames
dfs = [df1,df2,df3,df4]
```

---

```
#for each column test missing values and create union of masks
m = np.logical_and.reduce([x[2].notna() for x in dfs])

#for each e.g. second column test missing values and create union of masks
#m = np.logical_or.reduce([x.iloc[:, 1].isna() for x in dfs])

#filter list of Dataframes by union of masks
dfs = [x[m] for x in dfs]

#if need separately all DataFrames
df1,df2,df3,df4 = dfs
```

```
print (df1)
   0    1    2
1  5  4.0  0.0
2  0  NaN  3.0

print (df2)
   0    1    2
1  4  0.0  5.0
2  0  1.0  1.0

print (df3)
     0    1  2
1  NaN  NaN  0
2  4.0  1.0  5

print (df4)
   0    1    2
1  1  NaN  4.0
2  0  1.0  2.0
```

---

```
df_big = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=('df1','df2','df3','df4'))

df_big = df_big[df_big.xs(2, axis=1, level=1).notna().all(axis=1)]
print (df_big)
  df1           df2            df3         df4          
    0    1    2   0    1    2    0    1  2   0    1    2
1   5  4.0  0.0   4  0.0  5.0  NaN  NaN  0   1  NaN  4.0
2   0  NaN  3.0   0  1.0  1.0  4.0  1.0  5   0  1.0  2.0

df1, df2, df3, df4 = df_big['df1'],df_big['df2'],df_big['df3'],df_big['df4']
```

```
print (df1)
   0    1    2
1  5  4.0  0.0
2  0  NaN  3.0

print (df2)
   0    1    2
1  4  0.0  5.0
2  0  1.0  1.0

print (df3)
     0    1  2
1  NaN  NaN  0
2  4.0  1.0  5

print (df4)
   0    1    2
1  1  NaN  4.0
2  0  1.0  2.0
```